# Anchor Tag Not Routing to Expected Page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an anchor tag, which when clicked I want it to open this route http://localhost:3000/shops/1 where 1 is the id of the seller_profile, however I am getting this error
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"seller_profiles", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]

```
<a href="<%=seller_profile_path(@profile_of_current_seller)%>" class="navbar-item"><span class="icon"><%= image_tag "user.svg"%></span><span>My Profile</span></a>
```

```
class SellerProfile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :seller
end
```

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :profile_of_current_seller
  
  def profile_of_current_seller
    @profile_of_current_seller ||= Shop.find(seller_id:session[:seller_id]) if session[:seller_id]
  end
  
end
```

```
resources :sellers do
    resources :seller_profiles, shallow: true
  end
```

```
class SellerProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_seller_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :index]
  
  # GET /seller_profiles/1
  # GET /seller_profiles/1.json
  def show
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_seller 
      @seller = current_seller
    end
    def set_seller_profile
      @seller_profile = SellerProfile.find(params[:id])
    end   
end
```

Comment: Can you also add your SellersProfilesController, since the request will be handled by that controller's show action.

Comment: Where/how are you setting `session[:seller_id]`

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because `@profile_of_current_seller` is nil. In the above scenario `seller_profile_path(@profile_of_current_seller)` is the same as `seller_profile_path(nil)`. You would want to pass `seller_profile_path` an instance of seller_profile.

Assuming you have access to `@seller_profile`, amend your anchor tag to the following:

```
<a href="<%=seller_profile_path(@seller_profile)%>" class="navbar-item"><span class="icon"><%= image_tag "user.svg"%></span><span>My Profile</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@profile_of_current_seller ||= Shop.find(seller_id:session[:seller_id]) if session[:seller_id]
```

This code would cause a different error than what you are receiving if `session[:seller_id]` was present. Something like "Couldn't find Shop with id=". You should use `find_by` instead of `find`. Find only allows you to look up records by id.

```
@profile_of_current_seller ||= Shop.find_by(seller_id:session[:seller_id]) if session[:seller_id]
```

So, because you are not receiving the "Couldn't find Shop with id=" error, the issue with your link is that `session[:seller_id]` (and therefore, `@profile_of_current_seller`) is nil.

Also, in your controller you are using `params[:id]` to set the seller profile, but are passing the id of `@profile_of_current_seller`, which is an instance of Shop...so [Jeremy's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65795008/4988918) may help you out with that.